# Python Class and encapsulation methods

Tags: python, class, object, methods

I'm new to OOP and this is my first shot at creating a Python class. I am trying to make my 3 variables private and so that only the methods update the info (enforce encapsulation). It seems that if I remove the setters and getters methods from my class, it has no impact on my code (must be the initializer method doing the work?). What can I do to improve this? Thanks.

Edit- i've updated my code and removed the **init**. My getters are not working now.

```
  #Instantiate a new Pet Instance.
  myPet = Pet()

  #Get input from user.
  myPet.setName = input("Enter the pet's name: ")
  myPet.setTypes = input("Enter the pet's type (Dog, Cat, Bird, etc.): ")
  myPet.setAge = input("Enter the pet's age (in years): ")
  while myPet.setAge.isalpha():
    print()
    print("Age cannot contain numbers. Try again.")
    myPet.setAge = input("Enter the pet's age (in years): ")


  #Call the showPetInfo module using new instanced object.
  myPet.showPetInfo()




class Pet:

  #Fields of the Pet Class.
  __PetName = ""
  __PetType = ""
  __PetAge = ""


  #Setter methods.

  def setName(self,name):
    self.__PetName = name


  def setTypes(self,types):
    self.__PetType = types


  def setAge(self,age):
    self.__PetAge = age

  #Getter methods.
  @property
  def getName(self):
    return self.__PetName

  @property 
  def getType(self):
    return self.__PetType

  @property 
  def getAge(self):
    return self.__PetAge

  def showPetInfo(self):
    print("\n \n \n \n")
    print("Here is your pet's information. Your pet's name is {}, it is a {} and it is {} years old.".format(self.getName,self.getType,self.getAge))

main()
```

Comment: This question would be more appropriate asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You do not generally need or want getters and setters in Python. Nor should you set those attributes at class level; define them in `__init__` only. Don't use double-underscore prefixes unless you know *exactly* what you're doing (and probably not even then). And finally, Python style for method names is `lower_case_with_underscores`, not `camelCase`.

Comment: _"if I remove the setters and getters methods from my class, it has no impact on my code"_ Because you never use them.

Comment: Your code doesn't call the getters and getters so why do you expect them to have any impact on it? They are just dead code.

Comment: I've updated my code but it's not working. The assignment is asking me to use the 3 set methods to store the 3 values and the 3 get methods to return the 3 values.

Answer (score 2):

you are unfortunately right, they use to say setters/getters are contracts doing restriction for adults... (if I tell you "dont touch it" then you *shoulntd* touch it) but there is nothing restricting you and you can modify them!

same "feature" can be observed with "constants"... do in the jupyther or the terminal this

```
import math
math.pi = 1
a = math.pi
a
math.pi
```

and you will see that you now modified the constant pi value to **1**

many sugest to usse [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) but that is not a capsulation at all, that is just sugar syntax for the same "adults contract"  IMHO :)

so to your question

> What can I do to improve this?

document the code you are writing so the other part using it is aware about  how the code, instances states in objects must be handled

Comment: Well, access modifiers are only an "adults contract" that "I won't import java.lang.reflect;" ;)